# VueJS + Axios - CORS policy : No Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: vue.js

I have an error on a web application developed with VueJs that uses Axios.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at `URL API` from origin `URL APP` has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Example of a request :

```
axios
        .get(
          store.getters.getURL +
            "/TennisStats?MatchId=" +
            this.$route.params.id +
            "&season=" +
            season,
          { }
        )
        .then(function (response) {
```

I have a devServer set up:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'https:/URL_APP/api/',
  },
```

The application is hosted on AWS.

The error appears randomly and when the cache is deleted, it disappears again for a while.

I don't know what to do... can you reproduce the error and guide me in my search for the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try going incognito and trying? Might be a caching issue since you are working on the same machine. Also if this does not work try restarting the AWS server, or try running the hosted application on a different machine.